# Bucketing Using VBA

Tags: vba

Tried to Bucket data wrote this code can anybody will say what is wrong with this code.

```
Function BUCKET(
    range As range, 
    x1 As Double, 
    name1 As String, 
    Optional x2 As Double, 
    Optional name2 As String, 
    Optional x3 As Double, 
    Optional name3 As String
) As String

    If range.Value < x1 Then
        BUCKET = name1
    ElseIf IsMissing(x2) Then
        If range.Value < x2 Then
            BUCKET = name2
        ElseIf IsMissing(x3) Then
            If range.Value < x3 Then
                BUCKET = name3
            Else
                BUCKET = "NO"
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: What do you want the code to do? Where is the problem in your code? What have you tried?

Comment: when optional parameters x2 and x3 are missing, you try to compare them to some value... Maybe you should compare them when they are Not missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function BUCKET(
    range As range, 
    x1 As Double, 
    name1 As String, 
    Optional x2 As Variant, 'IsMissing needs Variant to work.
    Optional name2 As String, 
    Optional x3 As Variant, 'IsMissing needs Variant to work. 
    Optional name3 As String
) As String

    If range.Value < x1 Then
        BUCKET = name1
    ElseIf Not IsMissing(x2) And range.Value < x2 Then
        BUCKET = name2
    ElseIf Not IsMissing(x3) And range.Value < x3 Then
        BUCKET = name3
    Else
        BUCKET = "NO"
    End If

End Function
```